# What is the role of Streaming server like Wowza?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, h.264, rtmp, wowza

I have been exploring on how to live stream from iPhone. I will have to publish a stream at URL to Wowza server that I came to know. Other thing is that I will require a library for iOS to encode and compress the camera output and will have to send that stream over RTMP protocol to the Wowza server. At the receiving and, there should be a player which can decode, decompress that stream comes from the Wowza to the device like iPhone (a user who wants to see live stream).

My question is, if encoding is done through particular iOS SDK, RTMP has a role as a Protocol, a player at receiving end has a role of decoding, then what is the role of Wowza ? What is its function that makes it very important in the live streaming process ?

I have been searching on the function of a Media Streaming server since 3 days, but I could not understand the exact function of Media Streaming server like a Wowza.

I am desperate to the answer..

Any explanation will be appriciated, thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

I actually did a year-long project involving media streaming on iOS and I used Wowza.  The role of Wowza is to function as a media server that can receive the video that is broadcast from an iOS device over the RTMP protocol.  With Wowza, you have options to send http parameters that instruct the server to begin or stop recording the live video that is being streamed.  You also have the option of embedding video players in websites for live view.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Upvoted. Now I knew the role of Streaming sever. But I don't understand the flow of broadcasting from broadcaster to the viewer. I mean what will flow from where? Hope some explanation from you..

Comment: The iOS device broadcasts to the Wowza streaming server, which is installed and runs on your web server.  Your webserver can embed a video player to stream the live video to a viewer.

Comment: @SwiftMatt do you know any open source library to create RTMP video?

Comment: @SwiftMatt can you please tell me how to integrate wowza with LFLiveKit? is it possible? I am facing problem broadcasting live on slow mobile connection.